# Writing mapreduce output directly onto a webpage

Tags: java, mapreduce, hdfs, html

I have a mapreduce job which writes its output to a file in HDFS. But instead of writing it to HDFS, I want the output to be written directly on a webpage. I have created a web project in eclipse and written driver, mapper and reducer classes in it. When I run it with tomcat server, it didn't work.

So how can the output be displayed on a webpage?

Comment: This is a very open ended question.  Is there anything you have tried already?

Comment: I have taken a web project in eclipse and written driver, mapper and reducer code in it. When I run it on tomcat server, it shows a webpage saying 404 error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAP-R distribution , you can write the output of your map reduce job to the file system (not the HDFS), but to fix your issue will require more info.

Comment: when we do a mapreduce job ( word count for example), the output will be stored in a file (either in HDFS or local file system). But I want to show that output on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

HDFS (by itself) is not really designed for low-latency random read/writes.  A few options you do have however are WebHDFS / HTTPfs.  This exposes a REST API to HDFS.  http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html and http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/.  You could have the webserver pull whatever file you want and serve it on the webpage.  I don't think this is a very good solution however.

A better solution might be to have MapReduce output to HBase (http://hbase.apache.org/) and have your webserver pull from HBase.  It is far better suited for low-latency random read / writes.